# What is the formal news feed about the Bash language?

Tags: bash

What is the formal news feed about the Bash language?

I want to feel headlines like:

```
"Lambda functions now available in Bash"
"Arrow functions now available in Bash"
"Aliases are now available to be used in scripts as well"
"New sugar syntax for TASK XYZ"
"New argument for echo"
```

What is the formal feed, if there is one or at least, what's the closest feed to keep up to date with such changes, one at a time?

Comment: See also http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to the official GNU announcement mailing list: "Announcements about Bash and most other GNU software are made on `info-gnu@gnu.org`". However, that list is for ALL GNU software, not just `bash`, so you might get one `bash`-related announcement email a year, but also a slow stream of announcements about software that might not interest you.

The `bash` project itself does have its own mailing lists, with greater activity, but not for general announcements. People looking for help about bash, bash programming or bash shell scripting send questions to `help-bash@gnu.org` mailing list, so you could subscribe there to help answer questions or just to read the list. Likewise, there exists a `bug-bash@gnu.org` mailing list for reporting bugs or for discussing most aspects of developing bash.

Comment: I'd second this (and +1). If you have special interests in a project, subscribing to the project's mailing list(s) is a good idea. Be a lurker (someone who reads but doesn't write) for a while until you get a feel of what the tone of discussion is.

Answer (score 1):

I got [this link](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) from Pierre Gaston from the GNU staff. A Bash news file in [Chet Ramey's](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/) homepage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unoficcial mirror on GitHub, so one can subsribe for new releases: https://github.com/bminor/bash

And there is a NEWS file in the repository with latest release changes.

Comment: The official repo is https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/, see [the devel branch](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/log/?h=devel) for instance. You can tell Chet Ramey doesn't really use git internally though. See https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/log/CWRU/CWRU.chlog?h=devel for a more useful changelog